# Converting timestamps in php

Tags: php

I got time stamp in this format from twitter api.

```
Fri Dec 28 20:06:38 +0000 2012
```

I want to convert this to standard time stamp format like this one.

```
2012-12-10 16:20:18
```

Am pretty new to dates in php. How can I do it??

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two formats, but I might be reading it wrong. Are you sure the second format is correct?

Comment: I tried squinting my eyes but both formats read the same.

Comment: your two formats seem to be the same..!

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php](strtotime())

Comment: Specify the input format explicitly, don't depend on the parser's intelligent guesses. [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('Fri Dec 28 20:06:38 +0000 2012');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The reason why I prefer `DateTime` is that it gives great oop implementation and makes it easier to work with dates that are quite big head-ache of programmer. For more information about this class read the manual that I have already referenced.

Comment: +1, preferring [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) over [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) as well

Comment: If PHP is below 5.3, then IMHO `strtotime` and `date` combination is way to go.

Comment: @PLB: well, they still continue on _some servers_ :(

Comment: Those should not be supported though to make people move away from crappy hosting companies that use old php versions :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert the initial string to a UNIX timestamp and then [`strftime`](http://php.net/strftime) to convert it back to a string:

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime('Fri Dec 28 20:06:38 +0000 2012'));
```

That call returns the string *2012-12-28 21:06:38* - i.e. exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In case of use **php < 5.2.0** (some shared hostings) use a combination of [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Fri Dec 28 20:06:38 +0000 2012'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $originalDate = "Fri Dec 28 20:06:38 +0000 2012";
 echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/AhLcEU